# Use of a variable in same statement it is defined?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, compiler-construction, llvm

**Short and sweet: Why does the following block of Objective-C code not produce a compiler error/warning?**

```
- (void)someMethod:(MyObject *)someArg {
    MyObject *t = [self otherMethod:t.property]; // Typo. 't.property' should be 'someArg.property'
    [t doSomething];
}
```

I understand the runtime behavior, as 't' actually points to an invalid memory address when allocated.

Eg. the above line of code is logically equivalent to:

```
MyObject *t;
t = [self otherMethod:t.property];
[t doSomething];
```

In Java this (if I remember correctly) generally causes a compiler error, as the variable t is guaranteed to have no valid value when the `property` getter is called. (Sure, it *has* a value, but it's not one worth having.)

I ran into this issue a few minutes ago and it took me longer than I would have liked to determine what the problem was. Why does the compiler not warn (in either code snippet) that the pointer `t` is being used before it has properly been initialized?

Comment: The javac compiler from Sun would error on that, yes (I suppose it's possible to find/create a compiler which would allow undefined behavior there, although the JVM's stack-based bytecode and Java specification would make that that very unlikely -- not to mention buggy ;-).

Comment: Yea, I was pretty sure this would have been disallowed using Sun's compiler. I find it strange that it isn't an error in LLVM GCC 4.2, especially considering it's a local variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the objective-c compiler is not related to the Java compiler, so there's no reason for it to handle the same error case the same way that the Java compiler would.

I agree it would be better if the compiler did at least raise a warning in cases like this, but in a language that allows direct manipulation of pointers it's really hard to reliably detect this case.  For instance:

```
MyObject* t;
MyObject** pointerToT = &t;
*pointerToT = [[MyObject alloc] init];

//now I can use 't', even though I never assigned anything to it directly
[t doSomething];
```

Comment: Thanks for the example - that's a good reason why the compiler wouldn't show a warning/error.